# How soon can we represent a number as the sum of two primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory, conjectures

Posting in MO since it was [unanswered in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354708/how-soon-can-we-represent-a-number-as-the-sum-of-two-primes).

Goldbach's conjecture says that every even number can be represented as the sum of two primes. But how soon can we find such a representation. Taking $20 = 3 + 17 = 7 + 13$ if we start searching from the smallest prime we will encounter the pair $(3,17)$ first and say that $20$ satisfied Goldbach's conjecture. We do not have to go all the way to the pair $(7,13)$.

> **Definition 1**: The smallest Goldbach prime of an even number $n$ is defined as the pair $(p_n,n-p_n)$ where $p_n$ is the smallest prime such that $n-p_n$ is also a prime.

I found that $p_n$ is actually much smaller than $n$. Experimental data for $n \le 230751000000 $ suggests an asymptotic relation of the form

**Question**: Let $n$ be an even number which can be represented as the sum of two primes and $p_n$ its smallest Goldbach's prime. What is the limiting value of

$$
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n \le x} p_n - \log x
$$

Experimental data for $x \le 2.25 \times 10^{11}$ gives a value of about $1.313$ and it decreases slowly.

**Additional data**: Given $n$, we can ask how large can $p_n$. For even $n \le 3.6 \times 10^{10}$, the largest value of $p_n$ occurs as the following values of $n$ as shown below by maximal $(n, p_n)$ pairs.

```
(n,p_n)
(4,2)
(6,3)
(30,7)
(98,19)
(220,23)
(308,31)
(556,47)
(992,73)
(2642,103)
(5372,139)
(7426,173)
(43532,211)
(54244,233)
(63274,293)
(113672,313)
(128168,331)
(194428,359)
(194470,383)
(413572,389)
(503222,523)
(1077422,601)
(3526958,727)
(3807404,751)
(10759922,829)
(24106882,929)
(27789878,997)
(37998938,1039)
(60119912,1093)
(113632822,1163)
(187852862,1321)
(335070838,1427)
(419911924,1583)
(721013438,1789)
(1847133842,1861)
(7473202036,1877)
(11001080372,1879)
(12703943222,2029)
(21248558888,2089)
(35884080836,2803)
```

Comment: These numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002373 with some references to the literature. See also http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, Nilotpal?